# Advanced GUI design in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-interface

Is it possible to design my form like 3D? Or having my form displayed as a rounded rectangle?

Are there some online tutorials?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? WinForms is intended to create native Windows applications. I can count on two fingers the number of apps that are actually *improved* by adding a 3D interface or creating forms with abstract shapes.

Comment: @Cody: Just because something is done one way by the vast majority of application developers doesn't mean it's the best way for the user base. Reference David Platt's writing. :)

Comment: @HardCode: Yes, it does. Consistency is *far* more important when it comes to user interfaces than creating the "best" UI. Users will learn to use your application more quickly and feel more comfortable with it if it behaves just like every other application they've ever used. They won't even notice the glaring "design flaws". And while there might be some justification in substantive improvements to the interface, there's really no way to justify 3D or irregularly-shaped forms, as mentioned in the question. I can definitively say that *neither* of those will increase usability or enhance UX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In WinForms you can use [TransparencyKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey.aspx) to set part of your form transparent. This allows you to create [rounded forms](http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/jake/archive/2008/05/19/beauty-is-only-skin-deep-part-deux-if-it-looks-like-a-duck-it-might-be-a-winform.aspx).

If you really want to go *crazy* with your UI look at [WPF](http://www.wpftutorial.net/)

Comment: Why you would want to create these "absolutely radical form designs" is completely beyond me. A duck seems quite well radical enough.

Answer (score 4):

The best reference I've read for this is Pro  .NET 2.0 Windows Forms and Custom Controls in C# by Matthew McDonald. There is a sister [volume in VB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590596943). Chapter 23 is probably the most directly relevant *Skinned Forms and Animated Buttons*, but you probably also want to master Chapter 12 *Owner Drawn Controls* and Chapter 7, *Drawing with GDI+.* All that assumes we are talking about WinForms not WPF. I know nothing about doing this in WPF. In general I've found this book quite valuable and a pretty fun read (for a geek anyway).

If you want to get started on the web and you don't know GDI+ yet, that's a good place to start. When I was learning GDI+ I found [Bob Powell's GDI+ FAQ invaluable](https://web.archive.org/web/20140714181132/http://bobpowell.net/gdiplus_faq.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You should try to google something about these APIs:

```
Private Declare Function CreateRectRgn Lib "gdi32" (ByVal x1 As Long, ByVal y1 As Long, ByVal x2 As Long, ByVal y2 As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CombineRgn Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDestRgn As Long, ByVal hSrcRgn1 As Long, ByVal hSrcRgn2 As Long, ByVal nCombineMode As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetWindowRgn Lib "User32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal hRgn As Long, ByVal bRedraw As Boolean) As Long
```

With these you can specify your own region to display and therefore to specify your own geometry.

But this is a long time ago. Have you considered using WPF?

Comment: API not necessary, you can use the form's `TransparencyKey` property

Comment: In addition to MarkJ's suggestion, there are also managed alternatives. Namely, the `Control.Region` property, which allows you to set an arbitrary region for any control, including a `Form`.

Comment: In fact I think this answer is the **[VB6 trick](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_transparent_form.html)** for rounded forms? I am still a fan of VB6, but there were many improvements in VB.Net and we should use them ;)

Comment: @MarkJ: Yeah, that's probably right. The fact it's no longer necessary to call the native APIs, combined with the old-style P/Invoke declarations definitely makes this look like VB 6 code. VB.NET does make things like this a lot easier. (Although I spend all my time writing API declarations in both languages...)